# Equivalent of a bar chart when less is better

Tags: data-visualisation, chart-design

My team and I recently worked on a project to reduce the electricity consumption of our company's operations. Our biggest success is that we managed to divide by 3 the consumption of a system and obtained similar gains on others.

I'm looking for a way to visualize these gains. I was thinking of doing a bar chart, but unfortunately, since low consumption is represented by a smaller bar, I find that the positive results look ridiculous compared to the old method.

Is there any type of chart that can be used to highlight low amplitude data compared to high amplitude data?

I can't share the actual data for privacy reasons, but I did quickly draw a graph to illustrate my point.[image]

as you can see, method 1 and 2 seem to have little impact with this representation.

Comment: How about just reversing it? Show the existing usage as the baseline and then your methods as percentages of the existing usage saved? Then more will be better.

Comment: Or if you just display the columns in reverse order with "Actual situation" first followed by the two new methods. I don't necessarily think that a tall bar will always be seen as something good. Energy consumption is something you want to keep low. If the graph is clearly labelled and perhaps the tall bars are black/brown/dark and the lower ones are green/bright, I think the message comes through.